# Allowing User to Resize JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

When the user moves the cursor over to the border of the `JScrollPane`, can I turn the cursor into two little arrows that are pointing at the opposite directions of each other thus the user may shrink or grow the entire `JScrollPane`?

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(buddyList,
    ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

layoutConstraints.gridx = 0;  layoutConstraints.gridy = 0;
layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 3;  layoutConstraints.gridheight = 8;
layoutConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
layoutConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 6, 10, 36);
layoutConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
layoutConstraints.weightx = 0.8;  layoutConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
layout.setConstraints(scrollPane, layoutConstraints);
add(scrollPane);//Adds the Scrollpane straight to the panel The class extends JPanel
```

Comment: This is possible, the the layout of the container that holds the JScrollPane will have to be one that will allow this. Can you show us your attempt via an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I haven't tried to, I don't know what it maybe in terms of, scrollPane.setResizible(true);?? I doubt that's even correct, but the scrolePane is displayed the way it is set up above, just not able to allow the user to resize.

Comment: You will of course need to use and add to the JScrollPane both a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener which can be combined in a MouseAdapter.

Comment: I will dig your answer and hopefully put an answer to my own question with your direction. Thank you

Comment: *"with your direction"*  That claim seems hard to believe, since you ignored the advice to post an SSCCE..

Comment: Can't you just resize the `JFrame` around the `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong place. If you want to allow resizing of the scrollpane, the scrollpane is the wrong object to look at. It’s the responsibility of the parent container (or its layout manager) to give or take space from the component (which happens to be a scrollpane here) and distribute it to other children. The simplest way is to put the scrollpane into a split pane. You may put the split pane into another split pane with a different orientation to allow resizing in both direction, however this will resize the direct neighbor of the scroll pane (the other child of the inner split pane) as well. There is no solution to this with all these layouts forming a kind of grid.

Note that with your currently used GridBagLayout in the parent container it’s very hard to achieve such a resize support. And even if you implement this tricky trick the GridBagLayout will always size entire rows or columns. Thus you will have the same problem as with nested split panes even worse.